# Error code 368 on post on like

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Recently, my application started to generate a new error whenever a customer uses it to like a post/comment. We use the graph API to create and destroy likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes
```

But we get a status 400 with the following body upon a POST:

```
 {"error":{"message":"You've been blocked from using this feature because you may have violated Facebook's Terms. Please review the Community Standards to learn what's acceptable to share on Facebook.\n\nIf you need help, please contact us.","type":"OAuthException","code":368}}
```

To be honest, it is hard for me to understand what my customers might have done to deserve this and I can't find any obvious way to "contact us". Is there someone who knows what might trigger this kind of error and what I could do to help my customer resume normal operation ?

Mathieu

Comment: What is your app doing? It sounds like your app's users are being detected as spammy / are liking too many things for it to be considered 'normal'

Comment: My app is doing nothing special: it is just letting users like posts/comments through a specialized GUI. My users do not seem to be doing anything special either.

Comment: How many posts and comments are you liking per day per user?